# Viewport height not working, content in bottom div is overlapping when resizing window

Tags: html, css, wordpress, viewport

I've used viewport height numerous times with success but this time it is causing me problems and I cannnot figure out why. You can see my issue on this web page: http://staging.chinahiking.cn/great-wall-hiking/wild-jinshanling-to-restored-jinshanling-great-wall-hike-1day/

```css
.top-container.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.viewport-height {
  height: 80vh;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="top-container sticky"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="viewport-height"></div>
    <div class="description-container"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

But for some reason, the viewport height is not registering. And, when I change the screen height, the content within .description-container overlaps the content in my .viewport-height container. Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can get the content within my viewport-height container to be either 80vh or 100vh?

Comment: `.top-container .sticky` won't target your element, as `.sticky` is not a child of `.top-container`. You're looking for `.top-container.sticky`.

Comment: @ObsidianAge Ok, that was a typo. My issue is not with that container, and that still doesn't solve my issue which is with the viewport height of the .viewport-height container.

Comment: Inspecting the element in Chrome dev tools does not show any styles applied to `.viewport-height` at all. Which of the multiple stylesheets is supposed to contain this rule?

Answer (score 0):

Make it height auto fix your problem because of contain problem is coming

```
.description-section-divider {
    height: auto;
}
```

If you need some white space give some padding as per your requirement else if you want to fix using height:287px then you hvae to write media query for that better suggestion take height:auto;